# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 7267 into shape (302,24,1)

Tags: python, arrays, reshape

I am reshaping a 1D array into 3D using the following. It works fine but it throws an error when `x` is 7267. I understand that it is not possible to slice an odd number as an int without losing some values. Would appreciate any solution to this.

code

```
x = 7248
y= 24

A = np.arange(x)
A.reshape(int(x/y),y,1).transpose()
```

output

```
array([[[   0,   24,   48, ..., 7176, 7200, 7224],
        [   1,   25,   49, ..., 7177, 7201, 7225],
        [   2,   26,   50, ..., 7178, 7202, 7226],
        ...,
        [  21,   45,   69, ..., 7197, 7221, 7245],
        [  22,   46,   70, ..., 7198, 7222, 7246],
        [  23,   47,   71, ..., 7199, 7223, 7247]]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is, of course, that in order to reshape `A` in this way, it must be that `len(A) % y == 0`. How you do this depends on how you would like to handle the extra values.

If you are fine to discard some values in order to shape the array, then you can simply *truncate* `A` so that `len(A) % y == 0`.

E.g.

```
x = 7267
y = 24

A = np.arange(x - x % y)
A.reshape(x // y, y, 1).transpose()
```

You may also truncate the array using slices.

E.g.

```
x = 7267
y = 24

A = np.arange(x)

A[:x - x % y].reshape(x // y, y, 1).transpose()
```

In the case where all the data must be retained, you can *pad* `A` with zeros (or some other value), so that `len(A) % y == 0`.

E.g.

```
x = 7267
y = 24

A = np.arange(x)
A = np.pad(A, (0, y - x % y), 'constant')
A = A.reshape(A.shape[0] // y, y, 1).transpose()
```

Comment: Thank you. But truncating removes 20 values there. I am looking for a solution where there is no data loss.

Comment: @ferrelwill then you need to pad your data to the next multiple of y

Comment: Thank you @L.Grozninger. That solution is damn well clear.